# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm facing this problem when I try to run my app

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ggg\Desktop\android\app\libs\support-v4-25.1.0.jar (The
> >     system cannot find the file specified)

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gumball.at.adventure"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-25.1.0.jar')
}
```

any help please

Comment: Check your libs folder that contains the support library or not  & change the targetsdk version 25 , minifyEnabled true

Comment: i did that but im still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your targetSdkVersion to **25**

and add this line

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

You can add dependencies from here

[image]

Comment: i did that but im still facing the same problem

Comment: Try to add libraries from project structure menu

Comment: can you be more specific please .. im new in android studio

Comment: Goto file-> Project sttructure -> Dependencies tab click on + icon and add library dependncy

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-25.1.0.jar')
```

to

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

for including jar library files in your project.

Best you can use gradle dependencies functionalities to add library in your project. Example

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
```

It will automatically download the required library to the project. You don't need to download manually jar files and add to the project.